# Replace NaN with existing value of the group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace, nan

```
    Name     Value
0   AA        33
1   AA        24
2   BB        23
3   BB        NaN
4   CC        NaN
5   CC        23
6   CC        45
```

How can I replace these `NaN` with existing values by looking at column `Name`? For `CC` I would like to get the max (but if it is too convoluted, then I am fine with either `23` or `45`). The expected output:

```
    Name     Value
0   AA        33
1   AA        24
2   BB        23
3   BB        23
4   CC        45
5   CC        23
6   CC        45
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can groupby and transform with max then fillna:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(df.groupby("Name")['Value'].transform('max'))
print(df)
```

---

```
  Name  Value
0   AA   33.0
1   AA   24.0
2   BB   23.0
3   BB   23.0
4   CC   45.0
5   CC   23.0
6   CC   45.0
```

Comment: Great! If I wanted to get the min then I'd just change the `max` to `min`?

Comment: @AK88 Yes exactly..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `lambda` with `transform`

```
df["Value"] = df.groupby('Name').transform(lambda x:x.fillna(x.max()))
df
  Name  Value
0   AA   33.0
1   AA   24.0
2   BB   23.0
3   BB   23.0
4   CC   45.0
5   CC   23.0
6   CC   45.0
```